# multiple view resolver in spring mvc does not work

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, url-routing

```
<bean id="velocityConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/html/"/>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
    <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value=""/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="order" value="2" />
</bean>
```

I have all html pages so it works fine with viewResolver but now I added jsp so created another bean with InternalResourceViewResolver. Somehow it doesn't seem to fall through jsp view resolver & gives exception `SEVERE: ResourceManager : unable to find resource '/users.html' in any resource loader.` when trying to access user.jsp

Controller code is

```
@RequestMapping("/layout")
public String getUserPage(ModelMap modelMap) {
    return "users";
}
```

Comment: Please share your controller code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should add prefix's value:

```xml
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
<property name="order" value="2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

[Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-viewresolver-chaining)  says :

> The contract of a view resolver specifies that a view resolver can
>   return null to indicate the view could not be found. Not all view
>   resolvers do this, however, because in some cases, the resolver simply
>   cannot detect whether or not the view exists. For example, the
>   `InternalResourceViewResolver` uses the `RequestDispatcher` internally,
>   and dispatching is the only way to figure out if a JSP exists, but
>   this action can only execute once. The same holds for the
>   `VelocityViewResolver` and some others. Check the Javadoc for the view
>   resolver to see whether it reports non-existing views. Thus, putting
>   an `InternalResourceViewResolver` in the chain in a place other than the
>   last, results in the chain not being fully inspected, because the
>   `InternalResourceViewResolver` will always return a view!

for your code to work; Please change the order of **jspViewResolver** from 2 to 1 like below,

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
<property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
<property name="prefix" value=""/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
<property name="order" value="1" />
```

as the higher the order property, the later the view resolver is positioned in the chain.